# Exercises in Probability 255: A variant of the SLLN

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

#### To Prove

In exercise 255 of Cacullos Theophilos, „Exercises in Probability“, I am asked to prove:

> If the independent random variables $X_1, X_2, …$ satisfy the condition
> $V(X_i)≤C < ∞$ for all $i$, then the SLLN holds.

By which is meant that $1/n Σ_{i=1}^n (X_i - μᵢ) \to 0$ almost surely.

#### Help

Earlier in the chapter, Theophilios states Kolmogorov's variant of the SLLN, which i wanted to use:

> Let $X_i$ be independent random variables such that $V(X_i)\to 0$. Then $1/nΣ_{i=1}^n (X_i-μ_i)→0$ almost surely.

In other words, if the averages $\overline{μ_n}$ of the $μ_i$ converge, then $\overline{X_n}\to \overline{μ}$.

#### My attempt

First centering the $X_i$ is a good idea, and dividing by $\sqrt{i}$ tightens up the variances: The random variables $Y_i≔(X_i-μ_i)/√i$ ($μ_i≔E[X_i])$ are still independent and satisfy
\begin{align}
  E[Y_i]&=0\\
 V[Y_i]&=\frac{V[X_i-μ_i]}{√i^2} = \frac{V[X_i]}{i}\leq \frac{C}{i}\to 0.
\end{align}
By Kolmogorov, we have
\begin{align}
  0\stackrel{a.s.}{←} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i-E[Y_i])
   = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i-μ_i}{√i}
\end{align}

I've noticed that I cannot use the converse of Cesaro-Stolz on the given assumption, because the sequence $n$ in the denominator satisfies $n/(n+1)\to 1$. I also cannot use simple estimates like $1/√i≥1/√n$ because the $X_i-μ_i$ are not guaranteed to be positive.

Is there a way to estimate out the $√i$ factor by a constant, or is my attempt at rescaling doomed? Or is there some other sequence $√c_i\to 0$ that I can use for rescaling for which this attempt works?

Comment: $\{\sum_n\frac{\mathsf{V}(X_n)}{n^2}<\infty \}\Rightarrow \{\sum_n\frac{X_n-\mu_n}{n} \text{ converge a.s. } \}$, furthermore, by Kronneker Lemma, $\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu_i)\to 0$ a.s..

Comment: @JGWang by what statement does the first implication hold? Can you expand this into an answer?

Comment: This is Kolmogorov (two-series) theorem: Suppose $Y_1, Y_2,\cdots$ are independent random variables and $\sum_n\mathsf{var}[Y_n]< \infty$, $\sum_n\mathsf{E}[Y_n]$ converges, then $\sum_nY_n$ converges a.s..